# Mongoskin - Remove Object From Mongo DB Using Parameter Other Than ID

Tags: mongoskin

In Mongoskin, I can remove an item from Mongo DB using:

```
db.collection('/users').removeById(req.body.userid, function(err, result) {
    res.send((result === 1) ? { msg: 'success' } : { msg:'error: ' + err });
});
```

The above will remove an object based on the user / system specified `_id` key.

Is there a command to remove all objects by specifying a parameter other than the `_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the parameterized version of `remove`:

```
db.collection('users').remove({ 'some_field': 'some value' }, callback);
```

Other than that, you could make it simpler to access by using the provided `bind` [helper](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin#usage):

```
db.bind('users', {
   removeByAddress : function(addr, fn){
     this.remove({ address: addr }, fn);
   }
});
```

Then, you'd call `db.users.removeByAddress('someaddress', callback)` and be set.

Hope this helps!